# Rank of product of matrices consisting of orthonormal column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I have a matrix $\mathbf X$ that is made up of $m$ column vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $m<n$. The column vectors form a set of $m$ orthonormal vectors. So $\mathbf X$ is an $n \times m$ matrix. The rank of $\mathbf X$ is $m$.

I have another matrix $\mathbf A$ that is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.
The rank of $\mathbf A$ is $r$.

Is it true that the product $\mathbf{X}^\intercal\mathbf{AX}$ has rank that is *exactly equal* to $\min(r,m)$? I suspect this may be true but cannot prove it. If it is not true, what matrices provide a counterexample?

Comment: I know that transpose(X) A X has rank that is less than or equal to min(r,m). This is elementary. But for A and X described in my post, is the rank equal to min(r,m)?

Comment: I can give you two rank $2$ matrices and the product will have rank $0$.  This happens because the image of one can be in the nullspace of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitvely not true. As a counterexample, consider
$$
\mathbf X = \pmatrix{1\\1}, \qquad \mathbf A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.
$$

---

One result that is illuminating here is the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem). If $\alpha_1 \leq \cdots \leq \alpha_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ and $\beta_1 \leq \cdots \leq \beta_m$ the eigenvalues of $\mathbf X^T \mathbf A \mathbf X$, then we have
$$
\alpha_j \leq \beta_j \leq \alpha_{n-m+j}.
$$
The rank of a symmetric matrix is the number of non-zero eigenvalues that it has. If $\alpha_i$ is the largest negative eigenvalue of $A$, then we can guarantee that $\beta_j$ is negative for all $j \leq i - (n-m)$. If $\alpha_i$ is the smallest positive eigenvalue of $A$, then we can guarantee that $\beta_j$ is positive for all $j \geq i$.

Putting all this together, if $\mathbf A$ has $k_-$ negative eigenvalues and $k_+$ positive eigenvalues, then $B$ has at least $\max\{0,k_- - (n-m)\}$ negative eigenvalues and $\max\{0,k_+ - (n-m)\}$. So, we have
$$
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf X^\top \mathbf A \mathbf X) \geq \max\{0,k_- - (n-m)\} + \max\{0,k_+ - (n-m)\}.
$$
For all symmetric $\mathbf A$, there exists an $\mathbf X$ (with orthonormal columns) such that this lower bound is attained; that is, the inequality is tight. This is a consequence of the converse to Cauchy's interlacing theorem; one reference for this converse to the interlacing theorem is *Matrix Analysis* by Bhatia (Theorem III.1.9).

You might find the following to be an interesting exercise: show that this lower bound is equal to $\min\{r,m\}$ **if and only if** either all eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ are positive or all eigenvalues of $\mathbf A$ are negative.

We can weaken this bound slightly to get
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf X^\top \mathbf A \mathbf X) &\geq 
\max\{0,k_- - (n-m)\} + \max\{0,k_+ - (n-m)\}
\\ & \geq [k_- - (n-m)] + [k_+ - (n-m)]
\\ & = (k_- + k_+) - 2(n-m) = \operatorname{rank}(A) - 2(n-m).
\end{align}
This simplified lower bound is the same as the other in the case that both $k_-,k_+$ are both greater than $n-m$.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Grossman. Based on what you wrote, "You might find the following to be an interesting exercise: show that this lower bound is equal to min{r,m} if and only if either all eigenvalues of A are positive or all eigenvalues of A are negative",  am I right to understand that X⊺AX has rank that is exactly equal to min(r,m) if and only if A has non-zero eigenvalues that are of the same sign?

Comment: @bemsoc Not quite. It is only true that $X^\top A X$ has rank exactly equal to $\min\{r,m\}$ **for all matrices $X$ with orthonormal columns** if and only if $A$ has non-zero eiegnvalues that are of the same sign.

Comment: @bemsoc For all $A$, there exists at least one matrix $X$ with orthonormal columns such that $X^TAX$ has rank exactly $\min\{r,m\}$. In fact, this will hold for "most" matrices $X$ with orthonormal columns that $X^TAX$ has this maximal possible rank.

Comment: Thank you, @Ben Grossman, for highlighting the part "for all matrices X with orthonormal columns".  I presume that "A is symmetric" is also part of the assumption that of the statement "X⊤AX has rank exactly equal to min{r,m} for all matrices X with orthonormal columns if and only if A has non-zero eigenvalues that are of the same sign." Or the statement is true for all A (symmetric or otherwise) that has non-zero eigenvalues that are all of the same sign?

Comment: Yes, $A$ being symmetric is part of the assumption that I should have mentioned.  I believe that characterizing $X^TAX$ for non-symmetric $A$ (where $X$ has orthonormal columns) is an area of active research

Comment: I just realised this @Ben Grossman. If A is symmetric and has non-zero eigenvalues, that just means A has to be full rank. Then the result is just what is well known, that is, if A is full rank then XT A X just has rank m which is equal to min(r,m). But I am not aware that the converse is true, that is, is the only way for XT A X to have rank m is that A is full rank? So I am wondering whether "if and only if" in the statement in our discussion should be just "if".

Comment: @bemsoc Look again at the counterexample I gave at the top. $A$ is of full rank, but $X^TAX$ has rank less than $\min\{r,m\}$.

Comment: Okay. I forgot X is not square.

Comment: @bemsoc Yes, I understood that $X$ is not square. Everything that I said applies

Comment: Yes, I agreed. What I meant was that XT A X would have rank min(r,m) only if X is square and I forgot that X is not square. Thank you @Ben Grossman. Your input has been helpful in clearing my thought about the problem I had behind this.

Comment: @bemsoc I get it now. You're welcome!