# Generalization of Sylvester's law of inertia to the case of rectangle matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, matrix-analysis

Sylvester's law of inertia states given a symmetric matrix $A$ and a squared invertible matrix $S$ of the same size, then $A$ and $SAS^\top$ have the same number of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues.

Question: I'm wondering if this theorem can be generalized to the case when $S$ is not a squared matrix. For example, $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $n<m$, and $rank(S)=n$.

Comment: @Simon [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4612184/81360) is related

Comment: @RobertIsrael Both $A$ and $SAS^\top$ are symmetric, even when $S$ is rectangular. The question is which properties of $A$ (if any) are preserved by this operation.